# Como ler tabelas de um pdf?

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estou tentando ler tabelas de um certo arquivo pdf, utilizando o `iTextSharp`, encontrei muitas respostas que indicam utilizar o `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, só que a minha tabela pode variar de posição ao longo das páginas do PDF.

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Você consegue ler o PDF como uma String

Comment: Eu sei, mas eu queria saber se é possível pegar a tabela de forma estruturada de um PDF

Comment: Se você tiver como ler o PDF e por algum caractere entre cada coluna e no final da linha.  Você poderia usar um regex para capturar um padrão de string

Comment: Não sou eu que gero o pdf :/

Comment: Eu não entendo muito sobre isso, mas você só conseguirá por string se você achar padrões antes, durante e depois da tabela. Mas se tiver uma maneira de uma função retornar a tabela como uma matriz seria muito bom.

Answer (score -1):

Uma solução para ler uma tabela de um PDF é utilizar uma abordagem em duas etapas:

1. Extrair o PDF em texto puro
2. Interpretar o texto puro com alguma ferramenta;

Claro que está solução só é válida se o arquivo PDF é textual, ou seja, não é contido por uma imagem principal.

Com a biblioteca `pdfbox.jar` é possível extrair o texto passando o parâmetros básicos “ExtractText”. Ex.:

```
java -jar pdfbox.jar ExtractText C:\CAMINHO\ARQUIVO\PDF\relatorio.pdf c:\Caminho\Arquivo\Saida\Saida.txt
```

Cada linha no PDF será uma linha n arquivo de texto. Cada linha da tabela será também.

Com o arquivo de saída, você pode interpretar usando o Pattern que é uma ferramenta muito útil para esta finalidade. Desta forma então é possível ler os arquivos PDF.

Arquivo PDF de exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Saída em texto:
>   
> Supervisor:
>   
> Lanofu Silva 
>   
> Data 
>   
> 06/09/2018 
>   
> ID Produto Data Quantidade 
>   
> 3 Parafuso Allen 6” 04/09/2018 300 
>   
> 9 Eixo 127 Revest. 04/09/2018 500 
>   
> 15 Perfil 3 12x15 05/09/2018 400 
>   
> 72 Caixa metálica 15x15x5 02/09/2018 100 
>   
> 70 Engrenagem helicoidal 1” Nylon 01/09/2048 100 
>   
> 45 Heline Drone 5H-12BR 02/09/2018 130

Um exemplo de Patter para reconhecer cada entrada de produção da tabela:

```
Pattern padraoLinha = Patter.compile(“\d+\s.+\s\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d+”);
int countEntradaProducao = 0;
For(String linha : Files.readAllBytes(arquivoTexto.toPath())
{   
    if(padraoLinha.matcher(linha).matchs())
    {
        countEntradaProducao++;
        //Faço alguma coisa
    }
}
```